# Spyder 4: Autocomplete suggests functions from the wrong custom module

Tags: python, import, module, autocomplete, spyder

Using Spyder 4 and Python 3.7, I import two simple modules to my main module.

```
import module1
import module2

y = module1.func1(10)
z = module2.func2(10)
```

with module1:

```
def func1(x):
    return 1+x
```

and module2:

```
def func2(x):
    return x+2
```

Let's say I want to call func1 from module1 again. After having typed `module1.`, my IDE's autocomplete suggests func1 and func2, see [WrongAutocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU3yr.png). However, func2 does not make sense since it is not in module1 but in module2. Choosing func2 will in fact lead to an AttributeError.

How do I deactivate this kind of misleading suggestion from autocomplete?

Comment: You can try to rebuild your virtualenv… Or launch a new code analysis.

Comment: You should use PyCharm instead ;-)